# Will a Shimano R7000 chainring fit my Ultegra 6800 crank?

Tags: shimano, compatibility, chainring

Recently I almost had an accident while putting more power on the drivetrain and after replacing both casette and chain at home I noticed the chain did not settle on the chainring properly. Now I am looking to get a new chainring and the R7000 caught my attention, but the information out there is a little confusing. Did anyone already try this set up? Alternatively can you suggest other brands which would make a perfect fit with my Ultegra 6800 cranks?

Comment: It may help to specify how much you care about looks. Between R5800/R6800 and R7000/R8000, the contouring is completely different in addition to the finish. To most people, the mismatch looks really bad, especially given the price of these rings. Function is another story.

Comment: For me the looks matter less. Function is the keyword. Will it match perfectly?

Comment: [Shimano compatibility](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?acid=C-455&cid=C-453) might give a hint. Same BCD and # of spider arms as the same(-old-)generation R9000 Dura-Ace, so probably yes?

Comment: I've got multiple answers from sellers saying it would not be compatible.

Comment: “I noticed the chain did not settle on the chainring properly” Is it actually slipping under load? Do your chainrings look worn (pointy shark teeth)?

Comment: @PajzsP You could be right, I'm not entirely sure but [here's](https://www.roadbikereview.com/threads/new-ultegra-8000-compatibility-with-6800.360975/post-5181698) another "probably not", even thought it is not clear why, maybe something doesn't line up where the chainring joins the spiders even if both have 110mm BCD/4 arms. Why aren't you considering original R6800 chainrings, at least in the EU there are still some offerings, despite probably being "new old stock"?

Comment: U.S. eBay have multiple listings for R6800 chainrings, used and N.O.S.  I have that crankset on my road bike and wanted to replace my 52t large ring with a 46t. All sizes still available in U.S. for this model